# what make orbitals and can they be destroyed?

Tags: atomic-physics, subatomic, orbitals

What is making an orbital to be an orbital? 
I mean how are the orbital formed. If big bang theory is true that there was nothing before the big bang then definitely these orbitals in the atom would be formed when an atom was formed.
What make these orbital? 
As they are made of energy then how the energy took a shape like orbital?
Is orbitals everlasting?
What is not letting the orbitals to not fuse the energy out or can say not letting the energy to escape?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What has the big bang to do with atomic orbitals? Who gave you the impression they are "made of energy"?

Comment: The word big bang is just to say that atoms are created after it nothing more

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look up the definition of what an orbital is again.
Your question doesn't make much sense.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Shapes_of_orbitals

The "Shapes of Orbitals" section should help the understanding.
I suppose by orbital you mean an atomic orbital, which is basically nothing else than a designated area in which the electron is likely to be found.
I don't see how this has something to do with the Big Bang, nor how an orbital can be made out of something.
Inside an orbital there exists a probability density, but the orbital is not made out of it.

Comment: As you said orbitals are probability density where an electron may be found. As Bohr said that there are orbits with almost same energy as that of electrons where they revolve agree. Hence as electrons are revolving in those probable areas called orbitals should posses energy agree. So as atoms were created after big bang (this is how I am relating big bang with this) then how electrons got that they have to revolve in this energy (for you this probability density) and how does this probable area was created? big bang theory is for just saying that atoms were created nothing more

Comment: @Nukul *"As Bohr said that there are orbits with almost same energy as that of electrons where they revolve agree. "* http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=bohr+model+wrong The Bohr model gets exactly one thing right for exactly one kind of atom. It's only value is as a teaching tool.